# How to iterate through json in bash script

Tags: json, bash

I have the json as below, i need to get only the mail from the above json in bash script

> value={"count":5,"users":[{"username":"asa","name":"asa
>   Tran","mail":"asa@xyz.com"},{"username":"qq","name":"qq
>   Morris","mail":"qq@xyz.com"},{"username":"qwe","name":"qwe
>   Org","mail":"qwe@xyz.com"}]}

Output can be as

```
mail=asa@xyz.com,qq@xyz.com,qwe@xyz.com
```

All the above need to be done in the bash script (.sh)

I have already tried with the array iteration as but of no use

```
for key in "${!value[@]}"
do
        #echo "key = $key"
        echo "value = ${value[$key]}"
done
```

Even i have tried with the array conversion as

> alias json-decode="php -r
>   'print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents(\"php://stdin\"),1));'"
>   value=$(curl --user $credentials -k $endPoint | json-decode)

Still i was not able to get the specific output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is valid json and the email field is the only one containing a `@` character, you can do something like this:

```
echo $value | tr '"' '\n' | grep @
```

It replaces double-quotes by new line character and only keeps lines containing `@`. It is really not json parsing, but it works.

You can store the result in a bash array

```
emails=($(echo $value | tr '"' '\n' | grep @))
```

and iterate on them

```
for email in ${emails[@]}
do
    echo $email
done
```

Answer (score 9):

`jq` is the tool to iterate through a json. In your case:

```
while read user; do
    jq -r '.mail' <<< $user
done <<< $(jq -c '.users[]' users.json)
```

would give:

```
asa@xyz.com
qq@xyz.com
qwe@xyz.com
```

NOTE: I removed "value=" because that is not valid json. Users.json contains:

```
{"count":5,"users":[{"username":"asa","name":"asa Tran","mail":"asa@xyz.com"},{"username":"qq","name":"qq Morris","mail":"qq@xyz.com"},{"username":"qwe","name":"qwe Org","mail":"qwe@xyz.com"}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `json_pp` tool (in debian, it is part of the `libjson-pp-perl` package)

One would use it like this :

> cat file.json | json_pp

And get a pretty print for your json.

So in your case, you could do :

```
#!/bin/bash
MAILS=""  
LINES=`cat test.json | json_pp | grep '"mail"' | sed 's/.* : "\(.*\)".*/\1/'`
for LINE in $LINES ; do
    MAILS="$LINE,$MAILS"
done
echo $MAILS | sed 's/.$//'
```

Output :

```
qwe@xyz.com,qq@xyz.com,asa@xyz.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Using standard unix toolbox : `sed` command

```
cat so.json | sed "s/},/\n/g" | sed 's/.*"mail":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```

Comment: unfortunately this will not work with complex objects

Answer (score -1):

With [R](https://github.com/jpospychala/rcli) you could do this as follows:

```
$ value={"count":5,"users":[{"username":"asa","name":"asa Tran","mail":"asa@xyz.com"},{"username":"qq","name":"qq Morris","mail":"qq@xyz.com"},{"username":"qwe","name":"qwe Org","mail":"qwe@xyz.com"}]}
$ echo $value | R path users | R map path mail
["asa@xyz.com", "qq@xyz.com", "qwe@gyz.com"]
```